# SharePoint, List.Items and List.GetItems(Query) and Linq

Tags: linq, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, list

Following on from suggestions, I am trying to use List.GetItems(Query) to retrieve my initial data subset rather than the entire list contents via List.Items.  However, whereas List.Items.Cast() results in a usable IEnumerable for Linq, List.GetItems(Query).Cast() does not.

Working Code:

```
IEnumerable<SPListItem> results = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[ListName].Items.Cast<SPListItem>().Where(item => item["Date"] != null).Where(item => DateTime.Parse(item["Date"].ToString()) >= StartDate).Where(item => DateTime.Parse(item["Date"].ToString()) <= EndDate);
MessageLine = results.Count().ToString();
```

Non-working Code:

```
string SPStartDate = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(this.StartDate);
string SPEndDate =   SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(this.EndDate);

SPQuery MyQuery = new SPQuery();
MyQuery.Query = "<Where><And><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Date'/><Value Type='DateTime'>" + SPStartDate + "</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='Date'/><Value Type='DateTime'>" + SPEndDate + "</Value></Leq></And></Where>";

IEnumerable<SPListItem> results = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[ListName].GetItems(MyQuery).Cast<SPListItem>();

MessageLine = results.Count().ToString();
```

The List.GetItems(Query).Cast() method produces the following Exception on the .Count() line:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException:
>   Cannot complete this action. Please
>   try again. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0x80004005): Cannot complete this
>   action. Please try again. at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListItemDataWithCallback(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String
>   bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml,
>   SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback,
>   ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback,
>   ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String
>   bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml,
>   SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback,
>   ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback,
>   ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback) ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String
>   bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml,
>   SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback,
>   ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback,
>   ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureListItemsData()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.Undirty()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseCollection.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.d__aa`1.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source) at
>   Test.GetTransactionsInPeriod() at
>   Test.CreateChildControls()

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: If you're querying SPListItems using Linq, you should look at http://spexlib.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that for future projects but its a little late for this one :(

Comment: Whilst this is already answered by [Michael Stum](http://stackoverflow.com/users/91/michael-stum), here is a working link to the U2U CAML builder: [U2U's CAML Builder](http://www.u2u.be/Software) Edit:
Just found out this is a feature which enhances the ribbon in SharePoint 2010 with a CAML builder.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the error message it looks like the CAML Query is wrong. You may want to run it through something like [U2U's CAML Query Builder](http://www.u2u.net/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) to double check. The error message is thrown by SharePoint before the requested casts. Glancing over it, I think you have an extra `<And>` at the beginning (`<Where><And><And>`)

By the way: Don't use SPWeb.Lists[Name]. This will load every list in the SPWeb (including Metadata), which is rather resource intensive. One of the SPWeb.GetList or SPWeb.Lists.GetList methods [is better](http://blogs.msdn.com/sowmyancs/archive/2008/10/26/best-practices-sharepoint-object-model-for-performance-tuning.aspx).

Comment: Well, wouldn't you know it - it was the CAML Query.  How did you come to that conclusion from that error message, I wouldn't have ever have put that together?  Thankyou for the suggestion of the query builder, it looks like its a very useful tool.  Also, thanks for the pointer on the SPWeb.Lists[] - if it applies to List.Items then of course it applies to Web.Lists!

Comment: @Moo: CAML queries are often difficult to get right. U2U CAML Query Builder that Michael suggests will save you heaps of time.

Comment: Experience :-) Two things: "Cannot complete this action." is the typical Sharepoint message for "Something is wrong with the CAML" - the other typical message would have been "One or more field types are not installed correctly", which is also unhelpful but clearly SharePoint. Then: LINQ is a .net Framework Technology, so it should have thrown a meaningful error message, so it had to be SharePoint. Generally: Meaningful Error = .net Framework related, Useless Error message = SharePoint related.

Comment: Also the fact that it's an SPException means it has to come from SharePoint, so it has to come from one of the "inner" calls, which only leaves two options: The call to Lists[ListName] or the call to GetItems. The Cast wouldn't throw a SPException, and neither would results.Count or results.Count.ToString()